find a basis of the span of vectors
Given that vectors $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ are linearly independent, and $b_1 = a_1 - a_2,\;  b_2 = a_2-a_3,\;  b_3 = a_3 - a_4, \; ... \;  ,\;  b_n = a_n - a_1$.
Suppose $b_1, \; b_2, \; ... \; , b_n$ spans V. Find a basis of V.
Is it right to show that matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & -a_2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &0  \\
0 & a_2 & -a_3 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & a_3 & -a_4 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{n-1} & -a_n \\
-a_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_n
\end{bmatrix}
has rank = k-1. Will it be enough to claim that all possible combinations of k-1 vectors will be a basis? Or do i also need to clarify that every vector $b_i$ can be expressed in terms of other k-1 vectors?

What do you mean for "find all basis of vectors"? There are infinitely many basis once you find one. Indeed your matrix has rank $n - 1$, since all the rows add up to $0$, and the first $n - 1$ rows are linearly independent (just look at a column and argue).

I'm fairly sure you have transcribed something incorrectly, and/or something is missing. Are you having trouble with English? Can you consult fellow students. Also, please study our abridged guide to new askers.

I think i misunderstood the assignment, i got it now, thank you.

Can you work out the answer by looking at a similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480485/let-v-be-a-vector-space-with-basis-e-1-e-n-is-e-1-e-2-e-2-e-3-e-3/4480499#4480499 ?
